# Need help converting a list of CIDR to network ranges. SED/AWK or anything

Tags: bash, sed, expression, cidr

Ok, so I am trying to convert a list of CIDR formatted ip data into netranges

192.168.1.0/24 I need that, converted to 192.168.1.0-255

In fact, a whole list of addresses. Like this.

```
101.192.0.0/14
101.202.0.0/16
101.203.128.0/19
101.248.0.0/15
101.252.0.0/15
103.16.76.0/24
103.194.8.0/22
103.197.8.0/22
103.205.84.0/22
103.207.160.0/22
103.210.12.0/22
103.215.80.0/22
103.229.36.0/22
103.229.40.0/22
103.230.144.0/22
103.232.136.0/22
103.232.172.0/22
103.236.32.0/22
```

Is there any tools readily available that do this? I did some searching before posting this, but nobody else seems to be going for the specific output that I am trying to get here.

Comment: You could write some simple Python 3 code using the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: What should your sample input produce as output, and what barriers are you experiencing with your own code? Show your code, please. We can't help you fix it unless we see it.

Comment: What would be your expected output with this inpout: `101.192.0.0/14`?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried without external commands or libraries.

```
perl -pe '
    m#^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/(\d+)#;
    $_ = "$1.$2.$3.$4-" . join(".", map(hex, sprintf("%X", ($1 << 24) + ($2 << 16) + ($3 << 8) + $4 | (1 << (32 - $5)) - 1) =~ /.{2}/g)) . "\n";
' iplist.txt
```

Comment: Nice, I think this is the most native way to do it by using bit shifting and masking.

Answer (score 0):

I provide the sample script using ipaddress.(Thank you for the instructions, @Jonathon Reinhart )

The prerequisite task is just installing ipaddress module.

```
# pip install ipaddress
```

script code: the cidr.list file is including above cidr list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ipaddress

file_path='/tmp/cidr.list'

with open(file_path,'r') as cidr_list:
  for cidr in cidr_list:
    tmp = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(cidr[:-1]))
    print "%s-%s" % (tmp[0],tmp[-1])
```

output:

```
101.192.0.0-101.195.255.255
101.202.0.0-101.202.255.255
101.203.128.0-101.203.159.255
101.248.0.0-101.249.255.255
101.252.0.0-101.253.255.255
103.16.76.0-103.16.76.255
103.194.8.0-103.194.11.255
103.197.8.0-103.197.11.255
103.205.84.0-103.205.87.255
103.207.160.0-103.207.163.255
103.210.12.0-103.210.15.255
103.215.80.0-103.215.83.255
103.229.36.0-103.229.39.255
103.229.40.0-103.229.43.255
103.230.144.0-103.230.147.255
103.232.136.0-103.232.139.255
103.232.172.0-103.232.175.255
103.236.32.0-103.236.35.255
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: `101.192.0.0/14` absolutely does not match `101.192.0.0-255` In fact, all your results appear to assume /24.

Comment: Ouch! You're right @ghoti. But it's a issue based on a wrong output format. The logic is no problem calculating IP range. I modified the answer.

Comment: I agree that this is a failure with the question. Does he want what you've posted (which now produces the same as what etopylight posted), or does he want, for example, `101.192-195.0-255.0-255`? Who can say?

Answer (score 0):

**Update** (thanks @TheAdminsHereAreFags for pointing out `sipcalc`)

---

If you have the `sipcalc` package installed

```
sipcalc - < iplist.txt | awk '/Network range/{print $4 $5 $6}'
```

**Output**

```
101.192.0.0-101.195.255.255
101.202.0.0-101.202.255.255
101.203.128.0-101.203.159.255
101.248.0.0-101.249.255.255
101.252.0.0-101.253.255.255
103.16.76.0-103.16.76.255
103.194.8.0-103.194.11.255
103.197.8.0-103.197.11.255
103.205.84.0-103.205.87.255
103.207.160.0-103.207.163.255
103.210.12.0-103.210.15.255
103.215.80.0-103.215.83.255
103.229.36.0-103.229.39.255
103.229.40.0-103.229.43.255
103.230.144.0-103.230.147.255
103.232.136.0-103.232.139.255
103.232.172.0-103.232.175.255
103.236.32.0-103.236.35.255
```

Comment: That is a magnificent solution.  I installed sipcalc and found another way, which is not as sexy, But works.

Comment: @TheAdminsHereAreFags Thanks for mentioning `sipcalc`, what a great tool, now the solution can be much cleaner :)